# Access a method of the immediate activity in the back-stack

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

So the scenario is pretty simple.
I have two activities , A and B.
A is the homepage and you can go to B from A.
In Activity A there is a private method called *setupDetails()* to update cached user info.
So in activity B when an operation completes , I want to call the *setupDetails(*) method of Activity A (aka parent activity). Is it possible to do so ? No i'm not talking about *onActivityResults()* or a broadcast listener. I want to directly access that method from Activity B. I tried search for similar questions but could not find an suitable answer hence posting it here.

Comment: All activities in backstack should be treated as non existing as they might be destroyed by system without warning. So you should avoid ever accessing non-resumed activites.

Comment: I see , thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it is kind of hacky.

In `ActivityA`, create a `public static` variable of type `ActivityA`, like this:

```
public static ActivityA instance;
```

Before `ActivityA` launches `ActivityB`, it can store a reference to itself in the variable (ie: `instance = this`).

In `ActivityB`, when you want to call the method in `ActivityA`, just call the method on the `public static` variable, ie:

```
ActivityA.instance.setupDetails();
```

This should mostly work, but there are cases where it will not work. One example is if you have launched `ActivityB` and then the app goes to the background. After some period of inactivity, Android will kill the OS process hosting the app. When the user returns to the app, Android will create a new OS process for the app and instantiate ONLY `ActivityB`. In this case, there is no instance of `ActivityA`, so the variable `ActivityA.instance` will be `null`. To prevent a NPE, you can check for this condition.